# How can I churn or send an individual Monero input?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, privacy, available-outputs, sweep-transaction, churn

In some situations, Monero's users should avoid linkages between outputs that they control. Some users may desire more anonymity sets than single ring signatures provide. To this end, the users may want to churn individual inputs/outputs before using them or combining them. How might one do this using the official CLI wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open and sync the CLI
2. Type `incoming_transfers available verbose` and press enter. This will return all of the outputs in the account and the associated information. [More info](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2634).
3. Find the output you want to churn.
4. Use the command `sweep_single [<priority>] [<ring_size>] [outputs=<N>] <key_image> <address> [<payment_id>]`. Example: `sweep_single unimportant f2e713dc54a9b1ec9c4925793ee1f35636234c8b99b7dd168791677e51e704df 9vfmz4q7LGQYMisHnLZzUCW1kjG35394sK14D3EfRK9xabR2VouaNSDYdTE5EeSvTe5WV2e6tFUFrEbC8gaHk85oCM4uz8g`

You can leave the ringsize blank since Monero now uses a mandatory ringsize.

The output with the associated key image will be sent to the specified address. If you want to churn, send the output to your own address. You can also use this feature to send specific outputs when sending transactions to others. This may come in handy when you would like to send already-churned outputs, for example.