# How to use custom output when signing?

Tags: ring-signatures, output-selection

So let's say I received 2 transactions to my wallet and I want to make a transaction.
I want to choose which one's output will be used to sign my transaction. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the Monero CLI wallet you have a couple of options:

If you received the two transactions to different (unique) subaddresses you can use the `transfer` command specifying the optional address `index` parameter (see `help transfer` for details).

Otherwise you can use the `sweep_single` command to send a specific output (see `help sweep_single`, and example usage in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10904/7493)).